# Broken psql. Cannot access psql client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, unix

I am trying to setup psql with rails 3+. I have followed this http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql and everything went ok. My database.yml has this:

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 8.2 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On Mac OS X with macports:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
  port: 5432

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  #host: localhost
  #port: 5432

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # The server defaults to notice.
  #min_messages: warning

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
  port: 5432

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
```

when I run 'psql -U root -h localhost -p 5432 -W' it does not connect no matter what password I give it.'rake db:create:all' fails too with

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"app_production", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"root", "password"=>nil}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The tutorial does not set `host: localhost` in `database.yml`. That difference implies that it's not subject to the same authentication rules in `pg_hba.conf` (it uses a unix domain socket, not a TCP socket). That **may** explain why it doesn't need a password whereas you do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you have PostgreSQL installed - on my Mac, I find it generally expects the database username to be my username, and no password. Are you sure you have it set up with a root username and a password?

Comment: I did not set up a password durin installation. leaving it blank it gives me, psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Comment: Are you sure the username should be root?

Comment: I tried root and my name. I don't think there are more users on the system

Comment: When you tried without a password, did you remove the `-W` flag?

Comment: What operating system are you on? How did you install PostgreSQL?